# Automating Jmeter tests as a scheduled task

Tags: ant, automation, jmeter

I am using jmeter to do some performance testing on my site. I will user ant to drive the jmeter tests.

Now the problem is I need to automate this process so I can run the test on a regular interval however the user does not have to be logged into the computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for a [continuous integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) system.

There are several available and on of the most popular of those is [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/)

Those systems let you build/test/whatever you project whenever code is changed or a build is scheduled.

Answer (score 0):

you can checkout how I automated the performance tests for one project here:

http://ibalosh.tumblr.com/post/35475979058/running-jmeter-tests-with-jenkins

We used Jenkins as CI system, and JMeter for perofmance tests.

Igor