# How to Run JMETER everyday at a specified time

Tags: jmeter

I want to run my JMETER test scenarios everyday at 12 PM, any suggestion ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automating Jmeter tests as a scheduled task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498286/automating-jmeter-tests-as-a-scheduled-task)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use linux Cron task or windows equivalent.
You could also do it from  jmeter by using scheduler but it's a kind of tweak.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jenkins it is pretty cool stuff and designed for such task only.